# Read file with multiple lines

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to write MIPS code to read a file which contain multiple lines:

```
Hello World
Hello World1
Hello World2
```

I've managed to read the file but can't get past the first line.

```
.data  
fin: .asciiz "file.txt"      # filename for input
buffer: .space 128

      .text

main:

# Open file for reading

li   $v0, 13       # system call for open file
la   $a0, fin      # input file name
li   $a1, 0        # flag for reading
li   $a2, 0        # mode is ignored
syscall            # open a file
move $s0, $v0      # save the file descriptor

# reading from file just opened

li   $v0, 14       # system call for reading from file
move $a0, $s0      # file descriptor
la   $a1, buffer   # address of buffer from which to read
li   $a2,  11  # hardcoded buffer length
syscall            # read from file

li  $v0, 4          #
la  $a0, buffer     # buffer contains the values
syscall             # print int

li      $v0, 10              #program done: terminating
syscall



# Close the file

li   $v0, 16       # system call for close file
move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor to close
syscall            # close file
```

The result output is:
`Hello Word`

Do I need to load the file into an array instead of a buffer?

Comment: What's the difference between array and buffer? Either is just computer memory. Anyway, you load 11 bytes (`li $a2,  11 #hardcoded buffer length`), but you have 128 bytes reserved in buffer, so you can read more. Even with 11 byte buffer you can still load the file in 11B long parts, but that will be impractical if some lines are longer than 11 bytes. Check your hello world text file with some hex-view to see how the string is encoded in bytes, and how long each line is, and what new-line byte sequence is used... use all that in code to detect end of line in binary soup of the file loaded.

Comment: And for simplicity for first versions probably create large enough buffer to load the whole file in one go, then code only parser over the data already in memory. Once you will understand that fully, you will probably realize how to code partial reader of file using limited buffer space. (about those 11 bytes ... "Hello world" is exactly 11 bytes long in ASCII encoding, so you don't even terminate that string correctly before calling `syscall v0=4` at end, you are just lucky that there's byte with value `0` after the "d" terminating it).